# How to print a parametrized SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oledb

How can I get a String with a parametrized SQL query, once parameters inserted ?

Comment: do you mean a string with the parameter values put into the placeholders?

Comment: Parameterized queries don't do value substitutions.  You would need to open Sql Server Profiler (or whatever profiling system is appropriate for your database system) and check out what the query looks like.

Comment: This isn't possible, the parameters and the query text are treated separately. There is never a complete SQL string, this is all handled at the database side. You'll have to construct it yourself by appending the parameter values into the query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're assuming that the parameter values will be injected into the SQL and that what ends up being sent to the server is a single string. There's no reason why that needs to be the case - although it could be in some cases.

Generally it would make more sense to send the parameters to the database *alongside* the SQL but distinct from it. That way there's less work for the SQL engine to do (e.g. parsing numeric values which have been convered into strings), less work for the client to do, less risk of SQL injection attacks due to a failure to escape everything perfectly.